# How to poll last modified file out of multiple files and send to target endpoint in apache camel?

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, last-modified

Here we have 4 files with different timestamp. We require to pick only latest one (first file with timestamp 18/08/2016 using Apache camel).

[image: demo]

How this can be implemented? I couldn't find much resource on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort the files by timestamp, and then tell Camel to only pickup 1 file.

```
sortBy=file:modified&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&maxMessagesPerPoll=1
```

You would need to turn of eager max messages also. See more details in the file2 documentation for these options: http://camel.apache.org/file2

If you are consuming from a file directory with

```
from("file:...")
```

Then you need also to consider what to do with the file after its processed, should it be deleted / stay as-is (eg noop). For example if you delete the file, then Camel will just pickup the 2nd last modified file on next poll, and so on.

If you need to delete all the files, then I am afraid Camel do not have that out of the box, and you may need to write some logic that delete all those files yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Seems quite easy using [`File::lastModified()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) over a folder and loop into `File::listFiles()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String folder = "D:\\Users\\tmp";
    final File file = new File(folder);

    long lastModified = Long.MAX_VALUE; 
    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        if (f.lastModified() < lastModified) 
            lastModified = f.lastModified();
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Oldest is " + sdf.format(lastModified));
}
```

In my `tmp` folder:

```
data.csv     08/08/2016
data.json    28/07/2016
index.html   17/06/2016
map.csv      29/07/2016
```

Output:

```
Oldest is 06/17/2016 09:53:10
```

Comment: This solution looks correct...How we can do same thing using Apache camel.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method provided by Jordi Castilla using a filter in Camel. See doc here:
http://camel.apache.org/file2.html
See the section on using filter.

Answer (score 0):

Check Camel's [File Language](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html). Looks like `file:modified` should help you